# How to insert a value to decimal type field using wpdb->prepare?

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I have a table myTable with a decimal(12,2) field named balance. I want to update the table using the following code.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET balance = %d WHERE id = %d", $balance, $id);
$row_affected = $wpdb->query($query);
```

The code works and the value in `$balance` is inserted, however, the value is inserted as 215.00 instead of 215.25.
I know there is something wrong with %d as it is used for integer value and not for decimal value, but I am not able to find the correct alternative statement to insert the value as it is.

Note: I tried using float data type with %f but that causes the unwanted rounding off of the values when inserted to the table, for example, 215.25 is inserted as 215.00 and 215.75 is inserted as 216.00, so I had to switch back to using decimal data type.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "using float data type with %f but that causes the unwanted rounding off of the values" Can you explain (by editing your question) what exactly this means? Would be best with an example I think. You should be able to set precision via `%.2f` e.g.

Comment: @kero, I have edited the question with example of what I meant by unnecessary rounding off of the values.

Comment: Is `$balance` actually a float in PHP or a string?

Comment: $balance contains a value that the admin inserts through a text field. I have tried type casting i.e. $balance = (float)$bal where $bal contains the string value from the text field, but of no use.

Comment: @AsmatAli, as @kero said, I believe `SET balance = %.2f` would work. And `wpdb::prepare()` itself doesn't require anything special, so are you sure the field `balance` has the type `DECIMAL(12, 2)`? Also, right before or after the `$row_affected`, you can do `var_dump( $balance, $query );` and just check the output.